# Google sheet script starting from the 1000th line?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet script to generate urls for googleforms that were submitted. The script has been working fine but now that number of submissions has increased substantially I keep getting "Exceeded maximum execution time" message.

How can I make my script start the loop from the 1000 line? Or the N line?

Or

How can I make the loop start from the last updated response?

```
function onOpen(){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  menu.createMenu('Get URLs')
     .addItem('Iniciar ', 'GetURL')
  .addToUi();
}

function GerarURL() {
 var formId = Browser.inputBox('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxxxxx/edit#responses', Browser.Buttons.OK)
 if (formId == ''){
  var formId = Browser.inputBox('URL not informed', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
 } else {
  formId.toString();
  var formulario = FormApp.openByUrl(formId)
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var dados = planilha.getDataRange().getValues();
  var respostas = formulario.getResponses();
   var coluna = planilha.getRange(Browser.inputBox('GG:GG',
                                                   Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)).getColumn();
  var hora = [];
  var urls = [];
  var set = [];
  for(var i=0; i<respostas.length; i++){
   hora.push(respostas[i].getTimestamp().setSeconds(0));
   urls.push(respostas[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var x = 1; x< dados.length; x++){
   if(dados[x][0]){
    set.push([urls[hora.indexOf(dados[x][0].setSeconds(0))]]);
   } else {
    [''];
   };
   planilha.getRange(2, coluna, set.length).setValues(set);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The function processes every formResponse every time it runs. So, if you have a million responses, and then get one new response, it will process the entire one million and one responses. An option might be to start the loop at the last updated URL - that is, only process "new" responses.

Comment: That would be perfected! How do I do this?

Comment: I suggest that you start by looking at the Execution transcript and see where the most time is being occupied.

Comment: humm I've tried finding my way throught google but couldn't figure out

Comment: Run the script and go to `View > Execution transcript` to see what's taking the longest, each step has a time next to it like this: [0.0015 seconds], using this you can see which parts of the code to improve.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Still trying to figure out tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should limit the responses by date by passing the function an argument: [`Form.getResponses(date)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses(Date)) (you will only get responses after that date.)

Secondly, store the last processed date in either the `PropertiesService` or in a sheet.  I would prefer a [script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()).

```js
// provide a default value for when property "last" is null
var last = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("last") || "2019-08-01";
var respostas = formulario.getResponses(new Date(last));
```

```js
// when finished
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "YYYY-MM-dd");
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("last", dateString);
```

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your help. I'll carry this tips in my next projects. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to reduce execution time by inserting only the last response URL to the row with the corresponding timestamp, you can do it like this:

```
function onOpen(){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  menu.createMenu('Get URLs')
     .addItem('Iniciar ', 'GetURL')
  .addToUi();
}

function GerarURL() {
 var formId = Browser.inputBox('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxxxxx/edit#responses', Browser.Buttons.OK)
 if (formId == ''){
  var formId = Browser.inputBox('URL not informed', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
 } else {
  formId.toString();
  var formulario = FormApp.openByUrl(formId)
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var dados = planilha.getRange(1,1,planilha.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var zeroSeconds=[]
  for(var i=0; i<dados.length;i++)
  {
zeroSeconds.push(dados[i][0].setSeconds(0))
  }
  var respostas = formulario.getResponses();
  var coluna = planilha.getRange(Browser.inputBox('GG:GG', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)).getColumn();
  var hora =respostas[respostas.length-1].getTimestamp().setSeconds(0);
  var url = respostas[respostas.length-1].getEditResponseUrl();
   if(zeroSeconds.indexOf(hora)!=(-1)){
    planilha.getRange(zeroSeconds.indexOf(hora)+1, coluna).setValue(url);
  }
 }
}
```

The change to your original code is:

- You do not loop through all the responses, but directly take the last one
- Instead of checking for cell, if its content is an element of the "hora" array, you rather check if the timestamp of the last response is an element of dados
- If so -you write the corresponding URL in the row containing the timestamp
- Compared to the original code, the new code contains less loops and arrays and should run faster

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I follow your line of  thought but for some reasson your code wont work for me. I get an error message saying "setSeconds" is not 
recognized as code..

Comment: Do all of your cells in dados contain timestamps?Try to set the upper range limit manually instead of getLastRow(), to make sure that there are no empty contents

Comment: @ziganotschka The OP did raise the option of "How can I make the loop start from the last updated response?", but this is not necessarily a good idea and coding for that scenario doesn't help. For example, what if the second-to-last response was new and hadn't been processed? This kind of scenario explains why the Op's idea is not wise. This code doesn't identify whether there were any unprocessed responses, nor does it update the URL for them (should they exist).

Comment: @tedinoz: I agree that processing only new responses might not always be wise, but given that the OP asked how he could do so, I answered his question.